# How to avoid unlist() modification of list naming

Tags: r, list

I am a bit puzzled by the names produced by `unlist()`. Please consider the following MWE

```
vector1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
names(vector1) <- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6)
names(vector1)
# [1] "1" "2" "2" "3" "4" "4" "5" "6" "6" "6"
list1 <- split(vector1,names(vector1))
names(list1)
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"
```

but then

```
names(unlist(list1))
# [1] "1.1" "2.2" "2.2" "3.3" "4.4" "4.4" "5.5" "6.6" "6.6" "6.6"
```

According to the documentation of `unlist()`

> By default, unlist tries to retain the naming information present in x.

so I can't make sense of this particular behaviour.

My problem is that the names as created by `unlist()` can't be matched against the names of the original `vector1`.

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit, please.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @RichardScriven I am trying to understand why unlist() output names such as `"1.1"` instead of what I would expect `"1"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
unlist(unname(list1))
#  1  2  2  3  4  4  5  6  6  6 
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: also `unlist(list1, use.names=FALSE)` which I think doesn't copy the list while un-naming.

Comment: @MartinMorgan --  But that drops the names altogether, which isn't what the OP wants.

Answer (score 5):

I sympathize with your frustration. R is (I think) trying to retain both the information in `names(x)` and the information in the names of the original components (consider the results of `unlist(setNames(list1,letters[1:6]))`, which makes the behaviour make more sense).

You can get what you want via

```
setNames(unlist(list1),unlist(lapply(list1,names)))
```

although it is admittedly awkward -- I would make this into an `unlistWithNames` function (or something sensibly named) if I wanted to do it often.  **PS** @JoshOBrien's answer is simpler, but I will leave this here because it explains things a bit more.

Comment: And it would've been hard for you to explain less ;).  Nice answer.  (I had immediately gone off to look for the more general solution for multiply nested lists which, I believe, is `setNames(unlist(list1, recursive=T), rapply(list1, f=names, how="unlist"))` --- very similar to your offering.)